# What is the name of this matrix theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**The Theorem**

Consider the linear transformation

### $ L:R^{n}\rightarrow{R^{n}} $

defined by $L(X)=AX$ for $X$ in $R^{n}$, then A is diagonliazable with $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors $X_{1},X_{2},.....,X_{n}$ iff the matrix of $L$ with respect to $S=\{X_{1}, X_{2},...., X_{n}\}$ is diagonal.

---

Does anyone know the name of this theorem and where I can find a proof for it?

Comment: Is it the spectral theorem? At least in part https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee127a/book/login/l_sym_sed.html

Comment: Is it NOT the definition?

Comment: Quang Hoang, what do you mean?

Comment: This is not a theorem, it is the definition of "diagonalizable matrix"

Answer (score 1):

Most probably this does not have a name because it's merely following the definitions.

Comment: Can it be proving or is it just a statement?

Comment: If you're in doubt, just prove it.

Comment: I don't know how!

Comment: @435145 What is your definition of diagonalizability?